# Overriding Django setting doesn't reflect in test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a separate `settings` file for test environment. I'm using DRF for Authentication, but have set the default permission as `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` in the `test_setting` file. Now to test whether authentication is working or not, I need to override the key. But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the decorator `@override_settings`. But it doesn't seem to work. **If I change the `setttings` file directly, then the test is passing.**

```
@override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
})
class AuthenticationTest(TestCase):

    def test_api_should_not_be_hit_without_authorization(self):
        response = client.get(reverse('some_api', kwargs={'key': value}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I'm expecting the status code to 401, but it seems to pass through and is giving me 200. 
I pasted the below code in the test and it shows that the `REST FRAMEWORK` was actually overridden, but the test is still failing.

```
from django.conf import settings
        dir(settings)
        print(settings.REST_FRAMEWORK)
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the response that I am getting:
`<Response status_code=200, "application/json">`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before when testing DRF endpoints as an authenticated user. If the user has access to the DRF [browseable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) views, an API request that caused a 401 can still be represented in a valid API view.

Try adding `format='json'` to your `client.get()` to ensure that you aren't hitting the DRF interface instead of the JSON API:

```
response = client.get(reverse('some_api', kwargs={'key': value}), format='json')
```

Instead of specifying the API format in `client.get()`, you could [change the default API request format](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#setting-the-default-format) in a test settings module so it's used in all of your test requests:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Franey, I added the `format` parameter to `cient.get()`. But I'm still getting 200 status code.

Comment: @nit710 It was a good try. Could you `print(response)` and include that in your question?

Comment: Done. Added the response.